# Have 71 rep but the system thinks I have over 75

Tags: support

[image]

How come? I'm only at 71 rep, not over 75...
I should not be able to place bounties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a relatively rare edge case. Today's reputation graph for you shows a change of 0:

[image]

This only happens when a reputation event occurred, but was reversed before it was saved. (Otherwise, no entry for that day is shown.) What likely happened is that someone upvoted a post of yours and then immediately un-upvoted it.

That put you over 75 reputation, triggering the privilege notification, but doesn't show up this way in your reputation history.

Comment: I see. I suppose that's why I still can't place bounties, then.

Comment: @aBe Mhm. On your profile, it indicates that your next privilege, placing bounties, occurs at 75 rep.